# Drawing many plots in one

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to draw plots using matplotlib and pandas.
In pandas I have data of price and dates of this price. All years in one file. In plot I want to get many plots for comparing increasing/decreasing price by months, every color will mean some year.
So my questions is there a simple solutions from matplotlib or pandas to not extracting every year and other little problems?

Comment: You should provide your data (or a sample) and the code that your tried so far to solve your problem.

Comment: @DavideBrex sample: https://hotline.ua/temp/charts/102320/63price.csv

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "pivot_table"
So code for similar tasks will be like this:

```
url="https://hotline.ua/temp/charts/102320/63price.csv"

fixed_df_t = pd.read_csv(url, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], 
                         dayfirst=True, names=["Date", "Price"], 
                                        index_col='Date')

r = fixed_df_t[['Price']].assign(year=fixed_df.index.year, 
                                 month=fixed_df.index.month) \
                .pivot_table(index='month', columns='year',
                             values='Price', aggfunc='mean')

r.plot(legend=True, figsize=(15, 10))
```